# R: Continue loop to next iteration if function used in loop has stop() clausule

Tags: r, function, loops, for-loop

I have created a function that reads in a dataset but returns a stop() when this specific file does not exist on the drive. This function is called `sondeprofile()`, but the only important part is this:

```
if(file.exists(sonde)) {
    dfs <- read.table(sonde, header=T, sep=",", skip = idx, fill = T)
  } else {
    stop("No sonde data available for this day")
  }
```

This function has then been used within a for-loop to loop over specific days and stations to do calculations on each day. Extremely simplified problem:

```
for(name in stations) {
    sonde <- sondeprofile(date)

    # Continue with loop if sonde exists, skip this if not
    if(exists("sonde")) {

        ## rest of code ## 
  }
}
```

But my issue is whenever the `sondeprofile()` functions finds that there is no file for this specific date, the `stop("No sonde data available for this date")` causes the whole for loop above to stop. I thought by checking if the file exists it would be enough to make sure it skips this iteration. But alas I can't get this to work properly.

I want that whenever the `sondeprofile()` function finds that there is no data available for a specific date, it skips the iteration and does not execute the rest of the code, rather just goes to the next one.

How can I make this happen? `sondeprofile()` is used in other portions of the code as well, as a standalone function so I need it to skip the iteration in the for loop.

Comment: Replace `sonde <- sondeprofile(date)` with `sonde <- try(sondeprofile(date), silent = TRUE)` and replace `if(exists("sonde")) {` with `if ( !inherits(sonde, "try-error") ) {`

Comment: That seems to do the trick! Thanks man! Running the whole code now, but it hasn't stopped at the same time. You want to post this as an answer so I can check it?

Comment: Sure. I was hesitant to post as answer originally since I didn't have data to check it with, but I'll post the answer now

Comment: Alright, I've added it, with some explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the function `sondeprofile()` throws an error, it will stop your whole loop. However, you can avoid that with `try()`, which attempts to try to run "an expression that might fail and allow the user's code to handle error-recovery." (From `help("try")`).

So, if you replace

```
sonde <- sondeprofile(date)
```

with

```
sonde <- try(sondeprofile(date), silent = TRUE)
```

you can avoid the problem of it stopping your loop. But then how do you deal with the `if()` condition?

Well, if a `try()` call encounters an error, what it returns will be of class `try-error`. So, you can just make sure that `sonde` isn't of that class, changing

```
if(exists("sonde")) {
```

to

```
if ( !inherits(sonde, "try-error") ) {
```